# PrimeReact Messages not work on useEffect (Comp Mount) ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm trying to trigger Messages on `useEffect[]`
but not working since the current ref is null, any idea ?
when I log the ref (pageNotification) on mount it shows null

[image]

I'm using react webpack TS

if I don't use chaining option will return error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'show')
```

The issue is my Messages component (notification) not runnning based on my useEffect because my ref.current return null, then i try to remove these conditions and it worked

```
   if (pageState.loading) {
      return <PageLoader />
   }

   if (pageState.error) {
      return <PageError />
   }
```

any idea what happen to my react code?

thanks in advance

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What are you setting your page state to initially? Can you paste the code instead of a screenshot